# boostrap datepicker allow to select end date as one day next to start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have situation where I would like user to select start date and restrict the end date to either selected start date of the day next to selected start date.
How can I do this on boostrap datepickers for start and end date

Comment: Please share a pen or fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download bootstrap-datepicker.js from  [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Start Date</label>
        <div class='input-group date'>
            <input type='text' id='datecheckin1' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" readonly />
            <span class="input-group-addon" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>End Date</label>
        <div class='input-group date'>
            <input type='text' id='datecheckout1'  class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" readonly />
            <span class="input-group-addon" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Java Script code

```
    var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var checkin2 = $('#datecheckin1').datepicker({
            onRender: function (date) {
//Here we restrict the date date of start datepicker
                return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {

            var newDate = new Date(ev.date);

            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
//Here we set the date of end datepicker
            checkout2.setValue(newDate);


            checkin2.hide();
            $('#datecheckout1')[0].focus();
        }).data('datepicker');
        var checkout2 = $('#datecheckout1').datepicker({
            onRender: function (date) {
//Here we restrict the date of enddatepicker
                return date.valueOf() <= checkin2.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function () {
            checkout2.hide();
        }).data('datepicker');
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

$('#dtpicker').datepicker({
                endDate: '-1d'
            }).on(....